# Why does activating conda unload my .bashrc configurations?

Tags: bash, conda

Ever since I added conda activate to my .bashrc file, opening up a new terminal on MacOS does seem to "unload" my .bashrc configuration. I have to manually call `source ~/.bashrc` every time.

Here is the content of my .bashrc file

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8

[ -f /usr/local/etc/profile.d/autojump.sh ] && . /usr/local/etc/profile.d/autojump.sh

. /usr/local/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
conda activate base
export GPG_TTY=$(tty)
```

If I want to use the `j` command now, I first have to source the .bashrc file again.

Anybody know what is causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: have you tried to put the autojump after the conda activation (line 4 after line 7)?

Comment: Just tried that now and it doesn't seem to make a difference..

Comment: figured out that somehow conda loads bash with .bash_profile instead of .bashrc. copying my .bashrc contents to .bash_profile has solved this issue!

Comment: Put it in as an answer and accept your own answer (may take some time before you can accept it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some digging, I found out that activating conda starts bash with .bash_profile, so I copied my .bashrc contents into .bash_profile and now everything works smoothly again.

Comment: The proper solution is to `source .bashrc` from `.bash_profile` if that is indeed the behavior you want.